# Team Foundation Server 2012 Source Settings

Tags: tfs, build

I've been asked if this is possible to achieve.

The TFS project folder is as follows:

mysask

-- API

---- branches

------ dev

-------- Directwest.API

-- CityGeocoder

-- SEO

---- Trunk

------ Directwest.SEO

The VS solution in api\branches\dev\dw.api contains a project reference to SEO\trunk\DW>SEO project.

This builds locally but not in TFS.  In my build definition I have 2 Working folders:
API/branches/DW.API
SEO/trunk/DW>SEO

And I have the build defaults to build SEO first than API since the API references SEO.

I think the issue is that DW.SEO's path is not under API.

My build fails as the vbproj file for SEO was not found. Where am I making my mistakes?

Comment: Can ypu share the exact error from TFS logs?

Comment: Drop Files to Drop Location00:00:00

InputsDestination: \\tfs\BuildResults\API Search Tech Dev\API Search Tech Dev_20140219.10
Source: C:\Builds\1\MySask411\API Search Tech Dev\bin


TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\Builds\1\MySask411\API Search Tech Dev\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.


Skipped execution of Revert Workspace because of BuildReason Manual

Comment: Exception Message: There is no working folder mapping for $/MySask411/SEO/trunk/DirectWest.SEO.sln. (type ItemNotMappedException)

Comment: This is strange as the Build Agent Folder is $(Source)\SEO\trunk\Directwest.SEO

Comment: This is really strange because the SEO project doesn't have a sln file as it's class project.  I think someone has messed things up and TFS is confused now.

Comment: Check in the Build definition, what's requested to be built